# Build is successful in Jenkins but AWS-Codebuild is giving plugin error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, jenkins, aws-codebuild

I have a project which is building successfully on Jenkins but when I try to build using AWS Codebuild it gives a plugin error. The project is basically a NodeJS and ReactJS project. We do not want to move to Jenkins as we are serverless and installing jenkins requires one EC2 instance. We do not want to maintain any server. I have tried below environments for AWS codebuild:

```
aws/codebuild/ubuntu-base:14.04
aws/codebuild/nodejs:6.3.1
aws/codebuild/nodejs:7.0.0
aws/codebuild/nodejs:4.4.7
```

The first four commands of my buildspec.yml is executed only when I use `aws/codebuild/ubuntu-base:14.04` codebuild environment. Otherwise only last three commands are part of my buildspec.yml

Below is my buildspec.yml

```
version: 0.1

phases:
  build:
    commands:
      - sudo apt-get update 
      - curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
      - sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
      - sudo apt-get install -y build-essential
      - npm install
      - npm run dev
      - aws s3 cp --recursive dist/ s3://$AWS_BUCKET_NAME/ --grants read=uri=http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers
```

Below is my error logs in AWS codebuild during npm run

```
ERROR in 
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
+ 3 hidden modules
```

Also, I get following warning during npm install in Codebuild but I do not get the this warning in Jenkins

```
npm WARN deprecated babel-plugin-react-hot@1.0.4: This plugin is no longer maintained. Please use babel-plugin-react-transform with react-transform-hot-reload instead.
```

Below is my webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var FlowStatusWebpackPlugin = require('flow-status-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        './src/app/index.js'
    ],
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        filename: 'index_bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                loader: 'json'
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|test)/,
                loaders: ["babel-loader"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
                loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader',
                options: {
                    limit: 100000,
                    name: 'assets/[hash].[ext]'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.styl$/,
                loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!postcss-loader!stylus-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: __dirname + '/src/app/index.html',
            filename: 'index.html',
            inject: 'body'
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery"
        }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            "process.env": {
                'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('dev')
            }
        }),
        new FlowStatusWebpackPlugin({
            failOnError: true
        })
    ],
    devtool: 'source-map',
    node: {
        tls: "empty",
        fs: "empty"
    },
    resolve: {
        root: path.resolve(__dirname),
        alias: {
            '~': 'src',
        },
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
};
```

Comment: Hi, just checking, where are you hoping to host the site (out come of the build)? Looking at the buildspec I would guess you are trying to host it in S3?

Comment: Yes, It is hosted in S3. @Riku

Comment: Amazon S3 does not support server-side scripting. You cannot host NodeJS code there.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html

Meaning your build should only run commands that out put the final fully static version of the website and upload those files to S3. Meaning e.g. npm run should not be part of the build process.

Comment: I am trying to upload the final static version only. npm run creates a folder dist/ and contents of that folder (which is static site) are uploaded to S3. It works just fine when I build from jenkins. But Codebuild shows error. @Riku

Comment: Ok, is this the complete error stack trace for the webpack error?; ERROR in Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html": + 3 modules

Comment: Yes, error is this only. @Riku

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145360/discussion-between-riku-and-deosha).

Answer (score 1):

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: __dirname + '/src/app/index.html',
  filename: 'index.js',
  inject: 'body'
})
```

`filename` option is supposed to be a javascript file? i.e: `filename: index.js`